# JSON output showing additional tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> how to remove

Tags: json, tags, output

JSON output showing additional tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` how to remove because it is working with IE but not with any other browser.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/zzz/abc.asmx/method",
    data: {},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    jsonpCallback: "SMS",
    cache: true,
    success: function (msg) {

        var c = eval(msg.d);
        for (var i in c) {
            treminalId = c[i]['DDD'];
            console.log(DDD);
        }

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/zzz/abc.asmx/method",
    data: formToJSON(),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    jsonpCallback: "SMS",
    cache: true,
    success: function(msg) {
        var c = eval(msg.d);
        for (var i in c) {
            treminalId = c[i]['DDD'];
            console.log(DDD);
        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});

function formToJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify({});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Post. But it is still showing below error in console. "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/zzz/abc.asmx/method